# Where can I cut a H.264 video stream without re-compressing?

Tags: h.264, video-capture

I am trying to cut a H.264 video stream without decoding and re-encoding. To find a cutting point in the video stream:

Do I first detect the I-frame and then capture the video for the desired time?

Am I right or I have to look for a combination of I, P, and B frames?

Answer (score 2):

Typically H.264 bitstreams start with a sequence parameter set (SPS), a picture parameter set (PPS), followed by an IDR frame in H.264 bitstream which is then followed by other arbitrary frames (P, B, etc). The parameter sets are required to initialise the decoder correctly.

Therefore to be able to decode each segment you're cutting, each segment should ideally begin with the parameter sets, but whether the each IDR is preceded by parameter sets is both codec and codec configuration dependent.
You'll be able to determine your requirements by looking at the NAL unit types of the bitstream you're wanting to cut.

However it is possible to supply a decoder out of band with the SPS and PPS. In that case they would be able to decode the bitstream starting at an IDR.

You don't have to look for combinations of I, P, B frames, just make sure you have the parameter sets, and your segment begins with an IDR.

Comment: Thanks, Raif. We have implemented a product that does everything mentioned in the question. Apologies for the delated reply.